# Grab the first 10 characters of each line in a file, from Left to Right, in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'd like to take the first x amount of characters from $line and move them into a variable.

How do I do this?

Here is my existing code

```
$data = get-content "C:\TestFile.txt"
foreach($line in $data)
{
   if($line.length -gt 250){**get first x amount of characters into variable Y**}
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

like this:

```
$data = get-content "TestFile.txt"
$amount = 10;
$y= @()
foreach($line in $data)
{
   if ( $line.length -gt 250){ $y += $line.substring(0,$amount) } 
}
```

Comment: lets say I wanted to get the last 10 characters from right to left.  would that then be $line.substring(10,0)
?

Comment: No. Will be $line.substring($line.length - 10, 10). First value is the start index of substrring, second value the number of chars to grab.

Comment: Or `$line[-11..-1] -join ''` if you want to be super cool ;-)

Comment: How can i use a variable in the $line.substring i.e.
     $strPart2 += $line.substring(0,$strLength)

Comment: Your example is valid if $strlength contains a number not greater than $line length.